# Rails: Facebook API - how to get list of groups, where I am included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am using FbGraph for getting information about pages I like, friends and so on, but I don't see there an option to get a list of user's groups.

Is there any way to retrieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read user's or friends groups you must have user_groups or friends_groups permissions.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups
```

this api call will return an array of objects containing the version(old-0 or new Group-1), name, id, administrator (if user is the administrator of the Group) and bookmark_order(at what place in the list of group bookmarks on the homepage, the group shows up for the user).

Checkout this [Client Side Example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/) page, Here testAPI() function currently getting user's name

```
FB.api('/me/groups', function(response) {
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.data + '.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your message, but how can I make this api call in my app?

Comment: just updated the answer. just using javascript you can get the result